# Go Unittest for Telegram Bot

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm trying to generate a unittest function in order to test the main function in my main.go file but it gets really complex when it comes to mock other functions called in main function function.:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

var ctx context.Context
var str string

func read_file() string {
    c, ioErr := ioutil.ReadFile("bigquery.sql")
    if ioErr != nil {
        log.Panic(ioErr)
    }
    sql := string(c)
    return sql
}

func get_query(client *bigquery.Client, message string) *bigquery.RowIterator {

    new_message := strings.Split(message, " ")

    q := client.Query(read_file())
    q.Parameters = []bigquery.QueryParameter{
        {
            Name:  "id",
            Value: new_message[0],
        },
        {
            Name:  "app",
            Value: new_message[1],
        },
    }
    // Run the query and print results when the query job is completed.
    job, err := q.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    it, err := job.Read(ctx)

    return it
}

func telebot(bot *tgbotapi.BotAPI) tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel {

    bot.Debug = true
    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)
    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60

    updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)
    return updates
}

func main() {

    ctx = context.Background() //connection with bigquery
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "my_project_id")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    for {
        bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("my_telegram_token")
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }

        updates := telebot(bot)

        for update := range updates {
            it := get_query(client, update.Message.Text)// returns row iterator

            if update.Message != nil { // If we got a message
                for {
                    var row []bigquery.Value
                    err := it.Next(&row)
                    if err == iterator.Done {
                        break
                    }
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Panic(err)
                    }
                    for i := 0; i < len(row); i++ {
                        str += "   " + fmt.Sprintf("%v", row[i])
                    }
                    str = str + "\n"
                }
                rpl := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, str)
                bot.Send(rpl)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am familiar with @patch in python and I searched for something similar in go as well but I only found this way to test:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"

    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5" // Import the correct package path
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

func TestReadFile(t *testing.T) {
    expected := "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE id = @id AND application = @app AND date < '2023-06-07';"
    result := read_file()

    if result != expected {
        t.Errorf(" FAILED, expected -> %v, got -> %v", expected, result)
    } else {
        t.Logf("SUCCEDED, expected -> %v, got -> %v", expected, result)
    }
}

// BotAPIInterface is an interface that matches the methods used from tgbotapi.BotAPI
type BotAPIInterface interface {
    GetUpdatesChan(tgbotapi.UpdateConfig) tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel
}

// MockBotAPI is a mock implementation of the BotAPIInterface
type MockBotAPI struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockBotAPI) GetUpdatesChan(config tgbotapi.UpdateConfig) tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel {
    args := m.Called(config)
    return args.Get(0).(tgbotapi.UpdatesChannel)
}

func TestTelebot(t *testing.T) {
    // Create a mock BotAPI instance
    mockBot := new(MockBotAPI)

    // Configure the expectations for the mock
    mockBot.On("GetUpdatesChan", mock.Anything).Return("id application") // You can configure expected behavior here
    // Call the function you want to test
    updates := telebot(&tgbotapi.BotAPI{})

    // Assertions and verifications
    assert.NotNil(t, updates, "UpdatesChannel should not be nil")

    // You can also perform assertions about the interactions with the mock
    mockBot.AssertExpectations(t)

}
```

it gave me this error:

```
=== RUN   TestTelebot 
    main_test.go:50: FAIL:      GetUpdatesChan(string)
                        at: [main_test.go:42]
    main_test.go:50: FAIL: 0 out of 1 expectation(s) were met.
                The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s).
                at: [main_test.go:50]
--- FAIL: TestTelebot (0.00s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    tgbotapi        0.016s
```

I don't know how to mock these functions since they are calling each other and it gets harder to mock each parameter. Is there an alternative I can use such as @patch in python.

Note: I tried to give updates := telebot(&tgbotapi.BotAPI{}) parameter mockbot at first but it gave this error:  cannot use mockBot (variable of type *MockBotAPI) as *tgbotapi.BotAPI value in argument to telebot
`your text`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign functions to variables and use those in the "main function".

```golang
var GetSQL = get_file;
```

Then you can stub I/O/ with something like:

```golang
func TestMainFunction(t *testing.T) {
        bu := GetSQL
        defer func() {
                GetSQL = bu // restore just in case
        }()
        // mockup file trieval
        GetSQL = func() string { return "SELECT * FROM test;" }

        // now test with stub safely …
}
```